# duplicate bundle in eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0)

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I use eclipse which version is Mars Release (4.5.0) to develop RCP application . In product definition file, I designated javax.servlet 3.1.0 bundle. But after I export product, I found a file javax.servlet_3.0.0_2011xxxx.jar in product plugins directory. It puzzled me a lot. Then I browse the Eclipse directory structures, and two jars exist in eclipse/plugins directories:   javax.servlet_3.0.0_2011xxxx.jar
javax.servlet_3.1.0_2014xxxx.jar
   I'm confused why there are two javax.servlet bundles. Even if there are two bundles, I had designate a version 3.1.0, why export wizard copy a wrong jar file?

Comment: search for `javax.servlet` in your workspace and see if there is any file pointing to "3.0" version.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.
In product definition editor page, a precise version.

Referenced from the picture above( I cannot upload picture now, sorry.), click Properties... button to enter an precise version 3.1.0.v20140161800. I must enter 3.1.0.v20140161800 instead of 3.1.0, because a bundle jar named javax.servlet_3.1.0.v20140161800.jar located in eclipse/plugins directory.
   Then I export the product, all is done.